# How to run exec()/ linux commands using gearman extension from cakephp application?

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, command, gearman

I installed gearman extension and gearman command line tool also. I tried to reverse a string using gearman from simple php file.

```
Example:
$gmclient= new GearmanClient();
$gmclient->addServer();
$result = $gmclient->doNormal("reverse", "Test the reverse string");
echo "Success: $result\n";
output:
Success: gnirts esrever eht tseT
```

In the same way i tried to run exec('ls -l') , I am able to execute using simple php files from cakephp application from webroot directory. filepath: cakephp/app/webroot/worker.php, cakephp/app/webroot/client.php.

```
worker.php

<?php
$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("exec", "executeScript");
 while ($worker->work()); 
 function executeScript($job)
 {
  $param = $job->workload();
  $t = exec($param);
  return $t;
 }
?>

client.php 

<?php
$client= new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
$cmd = 'ls -l';
print $client->do("exec", $cmd);
?>
```

How to implement the same type of execution using View, Controller from cakephp?
Workflow: Post data from View to Controller using ajax method and execute "exec() from gearman" , send output back to View as response of ajax POST methhod.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `exec`?! That brings a huge security risk. Use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) instead.

Your client code should be part of the controller.

```
<?php
class UploadController extends AppController
{
    public function directoryList()
    {
        $directory = '';
        // Get data
        if (!empty($this->data['directory']) && is_string($this->data['directory']))
        {
            $directory = $this->data['directory'];
        }
        $client= new GearmanClient();
        $client->addServer("localhost",4730); // Important!!!

        $result = $client->do("fileList", serialize($data));

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then from view use [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction).

```
$uploads = $this->requestAction(
         array('controller' => 'upload', 'action' => 'directoryList'),
         array('return')
      );
```

Worker could look like this:

```
<?php
$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer("localhost",4730); // Important!!!
$worker->addFunction("fileList", "getFileList");
while ($worker->work()); 

// From Art of Web
// http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/directory-list-spl/
function getFileList($dir)
{
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();
    $dir = $job->workload();
    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open directory for reading
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    foreach($d as $fileinfo) {
    // skip hidden files
    if($fileinfo->isDot()) continue;
    $retval[] = array(
        'name' => "{$dir}{$fileinfo}",
        'type' => ($fileinfo->getType() == "dir") ? 
            "dir" : mime_content_type($fileinfo->getRealPath()),
        'size' => $fileinfo->getSize(),
        'lastmod' => $fileinfo->getMTime()
        );
    }

    return $retval;
}
```

This is pseudo code. **Do not use it in production!!!** See Gearman [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.do.php) for more advance worker setup.

To actually take advantage of load distribution Gearman server should not be on localhost of course.

Comment: Goran @ I am using exec to run python, to run this I need user uploaded data information. So I am using ajax call to send and run python and send back response to View. How to implement gearman to this workflow? Is there any other better way to proceed.

Comment: I think that this should be another question. You did not mention Python at all. Your question is tagged with _shell_. Anyway, use [Python worker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gearman/) instead and call Python commands directly. Everything else stays same.

Answer (score 0):

Your worker.php needs to be already running on a server for this to work.  For testing, open up a new terminal window to the server where you want worker.php to run.  Start the worker: `php worker.php` on the command line.  (On a production server, you might want to look at [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to run your worker without a terminal.)

The code in client.php would go in your controller, but save the result to a variable instead of a `print` statement.

The fact that this would be from an AJAX call is irrelevant, it will work the same as a normal web page.  When the controller executes, the gearman client code will get a response from the worker, and you can output the result to the view.

Comment: Kris @ Thankyou for the reply. But I need some data to process client.php code from view to controller. Example: User will upload data and using ajax post data to controller function and run client.php code.